# fortran arrays same shape and size parallel in OpenMP

Tags: fortran, openmp, gfortran

I would like to ask whether openMP is capable of parallelizing fortran arrays with the same shape and size using *simple* notation. I did some research but I am not capable to find or figure out whether it is possible.

I refer as *simple* notation the following form:

```
a = b + c * 1.1
```

Find below a full example:

```
PROGRAM Parallel_Hello_World

USE OMP_LIB

implicit none

integer, parameter :: ILEN = 1000
integer :: a(ILEN,ILEN), b(ILEN,ILEN), c(ILEN,ILEN), d(ILEN,ILEN)
integer :: i, j

a = 1
b = 2

!$OMP PARALLEL SHARED(a, b, c, d)

    !$OMP DO
    DO i=1,ILEN
      DO j=1, ILEN
        c(j,i) = a(j,i) + b(j,i) * 1.1
      ENDDO
    END DO
    !$OMP END DO

    # is this loop parallel?
    d = a + b * 1.1

!$OMP END PARALLEL
write (*,*) "Total C: ", c(1:5, 1)
write (*,*) "Total D: ", d(1:5, 1)
write (*,*) "C same D? ", all(c == d)

END
```

Is the **d** loop parallelized with openMP with the current notation?

Comment: try `!$omp workshare`

Comment: The assignment fro `d` is not executing in parallel the way you desire.  Every thread is executing that assignment concurrently as each of the encounters the statement w/o a worksharing construct.  So, Gilles is correct that you will need to wrap the statement in `!$omp workshare` construct.  Because the `d` assignement does not depend on the earlier loop, you can also get rid of the barrier at the of the `do` construct, by using `!$omp end do nowait`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by [@Gilles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66890245/fortran-arrays-same-shape-and-size-parallel-in-openmp/#comment118240112_66890245) the answer to the question is to wrap it with the **workshare** clause:

```
  !$OMP WORKSHARE
  d = a + b * 1.1
  !$OMP END WORKSHARE
```

Find more info [here](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu39.html)